# Wiki instance mirrored to another box

Tags: mysql

I've never really done anything like this before, but I have a wiki instance setup on my internal network. Since it is a support wiki, in the case that our internal network is inaccessable through our vpn, we want to have the website readily available on a backup external site.

Our external system uses centos and so do our internal systems. So essentially I want to install a wiki instance onto the external system however I am curious how I would go about getting the mysql database connection going between the external site and our internal database.

I guess the question is.... what is the proper way to do this? Our database isn't huge, so some kind of sql cron job that transfers the database to our external box through sftp isn't out of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Just my 2 cents:

You could set up a MySQL master-slave replication, the master being inside the internal network and the slave on the external site.

You could also do a nightly mysqldump of the wiki, sftp it to the external site via a cron job and restore it there, but it looks like an ugly and clunky solution to me.

Perhaps the simplest thing would be to give up mirroring and have the wiki on the external site only, so it would be accessible in case of internal network downtime.